# How to pivot wider these dataset

Tags: sql-server

My test dataset

```
IdCx FecCx       OrderId Value
1234 2022-08-15     1    07:50
1234 2022-08-15     2    08:00
1234 2022-08-15     3    08:24
5678 2022-08-16     1    14:45
5678 2022-08-16     3    15:30
```

I require to pivot wider based on OrderId and Value
My expected result will look like (I do need the `NULL` in `Val2`)

```
IdCx FecCx       Val1  Val2  Val3
1234 2022-08-15  07:50 08:00 08:24
5678 2022-08-16  14:45 NULL  15:30
```

My first approach has been with `CASE` but resulting dataset will not coalesce rows, leaving a lot of undesired nulls

My [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf6c2731de5f945e7f2c5ff3f924d6cb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to aggregate - this collapses your NULL values into one row per group:

```
select idCx, FecCx
  ,max(case when OrderId = 1 then Value end) as Val1
  ,max(case when OrderId = 2 then Value end) as Val2
  ,max(case when OrderId = 3 then Value end) as Val3
from dbo.fact1
group by idCx, FecCx;
```

See [modified Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b45b676106e86dfbb22dc64b4676ac46)

Comment: The aggregate function of course! Ty

Answer (score 1):

Just in case `ORderID` is not sequential, we use the window function `row_number() over()` in concert with a `PIVOT`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=713e5e568d4ee748a131a235e9c15cc4)**

```
Select *
 From  ( 
         Select IDcx
               ,FecCx
               ,Item  = concat('Val',row_number() over (partition by idcx,FecCx order by OrderID) )
               ,Value
          From  fact1
        ) src
 Pivot ( max(Value) for Item in ([Val1],[Val2],[Val3])) pvt
```